# Escaping quotes and delimiters in CSV files with Excel

Tags: excel, csv, delimiter, double-quotes

I try to import a CSV file in Excel, using `;` as delimiters, but some columns contains
`;` and/or quotes.

My problem is : I can use double quotes to ignore the delimiters for a specific string, but if there is a double quote inside the string, it ignores delimiters until the first double quote, but not after.
I don't know if it's clear, it's not that easy to explain.

I will try to explain with a example :

Suppose I have this string `this is a;test` : I use double quotes around the string, to ignore the delimiter => It works.

Now if this string contains delimiters AND double quotes : my trick doesn't work anymore. For example if I have the string `this; is" a;test` : My added double quotes around the string ignore delimiters for the first part (the delimiter in the part `this; is` is correctly ignored, but since there is a double quote after, Excel doesn't ignore the next delimiter in the `a;test` part.

I tried my best to be as clear as possible, I hope you'll understand what is the problem.

Comment: You might replace all double quotes with a character like | = Chr(124) and reverse the replacement after successful import.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I should replace all `"` with `CHAR(124)` ? So Excel replaces all quotes with `|`, but how can I reverse it after in Excel ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

When reading in a quoted string in a csv file, Excel will interpret all pairs of double-quotes ("") with single double-quotes(").

so `"this; is"" a;test"` will be converted to one cell containing `this; is" a;test`

So replace all double-quotes in your strings with pairs of double quotes.

Excel will reverse this process when exporting as CSV.

Here is some CSV

```
a,b,c,d,e
"""test1""",""",te"st2,"test,3",test"4,test5
```

And this is how it looks after importing into Excel:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Import your Excel file in openOffice and export as CSV (column escaped with " unlike Excel csv, utf8, comma against ";").