# Delimiter of read csv is in text field

Tags: python, pandas, csv, text

I received extracted data from a server, the problem is the extract has the delimiter ";" in the csv file.

I read the folder with the following command:

```
files = glob.glob(r"path/*.csv")
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, sep=";", engine='c') for f in files]
df2 = pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)
```

and the output is:

```
columnA    columnB .... columnT columnU
2000        A      ....  I wish  NaN
1000        B     ....   that    NaN
this ends   NaN   ....    NaN    NaN
3000        A     .....    I      DUU
...
```

the text in row 3 belongs to the columnT in the second row. So far i am only possible to delete all weirds rows like row 4 but i am not able to keep that information.

```
df2.dropna(subset=['columnB'], how='all', inplace=True)
```

How can i read the files correctly? The Problem is, that in the text field columnT in the text it also use ";" as normal character.

the original text is (in csv):

```
columnA;    columnB; .... columnT;          columnU:
2000;        A;      ....  I wish;            NaN;
1000;        B;     ....   that; this ends;    NaN;
3000;        A;     .....    I;               DUU;
```

Comment: I'd say that's very difficult, as for any process, if the delimiter is purposely set to `;`, then a `;` in a text version of the `.csv` will always be seen as a new column indicator. You'll most likely need to clean the file before conversion.
Do you have access to the conversion/extraction process from the server? See if you can get the `.csv` with a different delimiter.

Comment: Could you show **as plain text**  an extract (with fake data if your want) of your csv file with at least the header row and one of the row containing the problematic data. Without that I cannot guess whether it is only a config problem or whether the file is irremediably broken or whether a possible workaround could exist. And please do not show what happens in a spreadsheet but the raw content as it happens in notepad, vi or any other text editor.

Comment: i added it as a small extract

Comment: No you did not. Your code reads the csv with `sep=';'` and what you show as the csv does not contain any `;`. I asked you to give the raw content not to bother you, but because, to be able to help you, I need to see exactly how the delimiters and quotes are used in the file.

Comment: got you, i added it now

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't aware of a programmatic approach to solve this (see my comment), but out of interest, a quick search led me to [Escaping quotes and delimiters in CSV files with Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43273976/escaping-quotes-and-delimiters-in-csv-files-with-excel). Perhaps you could try the same. I.e., either manually or programmatically, replace all single quotes for double quotes, and try your code again.